# Navigate file system in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When running hadoop fs -ls

```
drwxr-xr-x   - chiki supergroup          0 2019-01-14 17:03 Party_output
drwxr-xr-x   - chiki supergroup          0 2018-01-22 18:25 party_uploads
```

but when try to access the directory

```
hadoop fs -ls /Party_output
```

showing output as

> `/Party_output': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `hadoop fs -ls` shows the contents of your home directory `/home/chiki/`.

You need to run `hadoop fs -ls Party_output` to see inside that directory (because it lives in `/home/chiki/Party_output` and not `/Party_output`).